# How to get a list of all javascript files in a directory

Tags: 7, javascript, files

Is it possible to get a list of all the javascript files in the libraries directory? So far I have tried using files_scan directory but it's not returning anything:

```
$dir = base_path() . 'sites/all/libraries/';
$files = file_scan_directory($dir, "/.*\.js$/");
dpm($files);
```

many thanks.

EDIT

I changed to using `DRUPAL_ROOT`. This gives the correct path and returns an array of js files but there is a double slash `//` in the uri just before the file names: `/var/www/html/droop/sites/all/libraries//d3/d3.min.js`

```
$dir = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/libraries/';
$files = file_scan_directory($dir, "/.*\.js$/");
dpm($files);
```

Comment: out of interest, why do you need to do this?

Comment: a module with a field that to allows admin to pick from a set of js files to load with an HTML5 canvas element on each blog post.

Comment: that is because you have a slash after the path you are searching for ('/sites/all/libraries**/**'). just remove the trailing slash there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libraries_get_libraries](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21libraries%21libraries.module/function/libraries_get_libraries/7) should return an array of library directories, with the library name as the key and the directory as the value.

[libraries_get_path](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21libraries%21libraries.module/function/libraries_get_path/7) will get you the path to a specific library (js).

Follwing your approach, this works fine for me:

```
  $dir = "sites/all/libraries";
  $files = file_scan_directory($dir, '/.*\.js$/');
```

I think it might be base_path that is breaking it in your example, as it adds a `/` in front of the (relative) path from the site root.

Combining libraries_get_libraries with file_scan_directory will also get you libraries from profile and site specific directories:

```
$libraries_array = libraries_get_libraries();
foreach($libraries_array as $library => $directory) {
  $files = file_scan_directory($directory, '/.*\.js$/');
  $js_paths[$library] = $files;
}
dpm($js_paths);
```

It may be worth noting that these libraries may contain many javascript files that are not actually used by modules.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking into it a little more but for starters does dpm() show the correct value for `$dir`? Also, according to the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/7) the trailing slash on `$dir` is not supposed to be there.

code that is working for me:

```
$dir = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/libraries';
$files = file_scan_directory($dir, '/.*\.js/');
dpm($files);
```

Comment: Using DRUPAL_ROOT instead of base_path() fixes the path but there is a double slash in the file uri now (see my edit) thanks

Comment: Is there a trailing slash on `$dir`?

Comment: ah yes. It works with DRUPAL_ROOT if I take off the trailing slash and add a leading slash.  `$dir = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/libraries';`